# DalvikVm could not found class android library project

Tags: android

Need to tap the collective brain power here.  I am trying out a very simple BindService and communicate with Messenger example.  Since I am passing message object in the Message.obj field I defined messages in their own Android library project to be shared between service and the client.  I can compile fine by including the message library as a depdendency but during runtime dalvikvm complains it could not find class.  I have read other related issue dealing with export and orders but same solution doesn't help in my case.  It must be a very simple mistake but I am pulling my hair out right now.

App depends on SupportServiceMessageLibrary.

App has library before its src in project's order tab.

Lib is not checked for export in App since no one is consuming the App

Library is exporting its src and gen folder.

The error message from log cat:

```
01-31 01:53:41.134: E/dalvikvm(22886): Could not find class 'com.example.service.RequestStatus', referenced from method com.example.MainActivity$ServiceReplyHandler.handleMessage
```

Here are snippet of code

MainActivity

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Messenger;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.appserver.R;
import com.example.service.MessageType;
import com.example.service.RequestStatus;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView serverStatus;

/** Messenger for sending message to service. */
Messenger mServiceMessenger = null;

/** Flag indicating whether we have called bind on the service. */
boolean mBound;

/** Messenger for receiving message from service */
Messenger mClientMessenger = null;

class ServiceReplyHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == MessageType.MSG_REPLY) {
            RequestStatus reqStatus = (RequestStatus) msg.obj;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Class for interacting with the main interface of the service.
 */
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        // This is called when the connection with the service has been
        // established, giving us the object we can use to
        // interact with the service. We are communicating with the
        // service using a Messenger, so here we get a client-side
        // representation of that from the raw IBinder object.
        mServiceMessenger = new Messenger(service);
        Message regMsg = Message.obtain(null,
                MessageType.MSG_REGISTER);
        regMsg.replyTo = mClientMessenger;
        try {
            mServiceMessenger.send(regMsg);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
        }
        mBound = true;
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        // This is called when the connection with the service has been
        // unexpectedly disconnected -- that is, its process crashed.
        mServiceMessenger = null;
        mBound = false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_server);
    serverStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.server_status);

    Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent();
    startServiceIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
            "com.example.supportservices",
            "com.example.service.EntitlementService"));
    bindService(startServiceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    // Initialize messenger to receiver service messages;
    mClientMessenger = new Messenger(new ServiceReplyHandler());
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.server, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

And the message itself

```
package com.example.service;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.text.TextUtils;

public class RequestStatus {

public static int REQUEST_SUCCESS = 0;
public static int REQUEST_FAILURE = 1;
public static String TYPE = "request_status";
public static String STATUS_JSON_KEY = "status";

private int status;

public RequestStatus(int status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public static RequestStatus fromJson(String json) {

    try {
        JSONObject msg = new JSONObject(json);
        String type = msg.getString("type");
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(type) || TYPE.equals(type) == false) {
            return null;
        }
        return(new RequestStatus(msg.getJSONObject("body").getInt(STATUS_JSON_KEY)));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public String toJson() {
    JSONObject msg = new JSONObject();
    try {
        msg.put("type", TYPE);
        JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
        body.put(STATUS_JSON_KEY, status);
        msg.put("body", body);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return msg.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: First of all extract APK content and see manual is really this class exist here. APK is just zip archive.

Comment: Divers, thanks I was able to find the class in the library jar but did not see in the dex of the actual app.  I finally discovered my problem, embrassingly simple, to use it as an android library I would need to go to project property of the App and add it as a library under Android in addition to project dependency under build path

Comment: Yup, now it is in the apk as well.

Comment: Nice! to formally close this question mark my answer like a right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to project property of the App and add it as a library under Android in addition to project dependency under build path.